# Blazor - Cascading dropdown with INT ID not populatiing data

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I filled the below for and the country code was populated from a country table as a lookup based on the country chosen from the `InputSelect` column, "Country Name", circled in blue. However, when I fill the rest of the form and click on submit, it threw the errors shown below.

However, if I enter the same code manually in an inputText column, "Country Code", then it submits the form.

```
            @using ITSM.Data
            @using ITSM.Services

            @inject ISchoolService service
            @inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime



            <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="schoolmodal">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">School Detail</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">


            @if (CountryList is null)
            {
            <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            }
            else
            {

            <h4>Schools</h4>
            <EditForm Model="@SchoolObject" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
            <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <ValidationSummary />

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Location" CountryCode">Country Code:</label>
            <InputSelect @bind-Value="@SchoolObject.CountryCode" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">Select</option>

            @foreach (var item in CountryList)
            {
            <option value="@item.CountryCode">@item.CountryName</option>

            }
            </InputSelect>
            &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => @CountryObject.CountryCode)" />
            }
            </div>
            <br />



            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">Country Code:</label>
            <InputText id="CountryCode" @bind-Value="@SchoolObject.CountryCode" class="form-control" placeholder="CountryCode" />
            &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => SchoolObject.CountryCode)" />
            </div>
```

Table Structure

```
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
                [SchoolID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                [Location] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
                [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
                [PostCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
                [CountryCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
                [SchoolAdminPersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
             CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
            (
                [SchoolID] ASC
            )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
            ) ON [PRIMARY]





            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>


            </EditForm>
            }

            </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            </div>





            @code {
            private List<CountryModel> CountryList;
            //private List<SchoolModel> SchoolList;
            [Parameter]
            public SchoolModel CountryObject { get; set; }
            [Parameter]
            public SchoolModel SchoolObject { get; set; }
            protected string schoold = string.Empty;

            [Parameter]
            public Action DataChanged { get; set; }



            private async Task Closeschoolmodal()
            {
            await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("CloseModal", "schoolmodal");
            }


            private async void HandleValidSubmit()
            {
            if (SchoolObject.SchoolID == 0)
            {
            await service.Add(SchoolObject);
            }
            else
            {
            await service.Update(SchoolObject);
            }
            await Closeschoolmodal();
            DataChanged?.Invoke();
            }


            }
```

School List

```
            @page "/SchoolList"

            @using ITSM.Shared
            @using ITSM
            @using ITSM.Data
            @using ITSM.Services
            @inject ISchoolService service
            @inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

            <h1>School</h1>

            <p>Countries List.</p>

            @if (SchoolLists == null)
            {
            <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            }
            else
            {
            <br>
            <div>
            <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#schoolmodal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add School" @onclick="(() => InitializeTaskObject())" />
            </div>
            <br/>

            <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th>SchoolID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>PostCode</th>
            <th>CountryCode</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var SchoolItem in SchoolLists)
            {
            <tr>
            <td>@SchoolItem.SchoolID</td>
            <td>@SchoolItem.Name</td>
            <td>@SchoolItem.Location</td>
            <td>@SchoolItem.Address</td>
            <td>@SchoolItem.PostCode</td>
            <td>@SchoolItem.CountryCode</td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => PrepareForEdit(SchoolItem))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#schoolmodal" value="Edit"></td>
            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="(() => PrepareForDelete(SchoolItem))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModal" value="Delete" /></td>
            </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
            </table>
            }


            <ConfirmDialog OnClick="@Delete" />
            <SchoolDetail SchoolObject=SchoolObject DataChanged="@DataChanged"></SchoolDetail>




            @code {
            List<SchoolModel> SchoolLists;
            SchoolModel SchoolObject = new SchoolModel();

            private void PrepareForEdit(SchoolModel School)
            {
            SchoolObject = School;
            }

            private void PrepareForDelete(SchoolModel School)
            {
            SchoolObject = School;
            }

            private async void Delete()
            {
            var School = await service.Delete(SchoolObject.SchoolID);
            await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("Closemodal", "confirmDeletemodal");
            SchoolLists = await service.Get();
            SchoolObject = new SchoolModel();
            StateHasChanged();
            }

            protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
            {
            SchoolLists = await service.Get();

            }
            private void InitializeTaskObject()
            {
            SchoolObject = new SchoolModel();
            }
            private async void DataChanged()
            {
            SchoolLists = await service.Get();
            StateHasChanged();
            }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your code. It's impossible to tell what is wrong without seeing some code. A wild guess is that when populating the fields based on your dropdown-choice the values are not  properly bound to the view model.

Comment: I've just added more information of my discovery after further investigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you have both a `newPerson` and a `newPerson2`, which makes things quite confusing. Also in your "Country Code" `Input` element you are actually not binding it to the `CountryCode` property, which means that `newPerson2.CountryCode` in `InsertSchool()` is always gonna be null.

I would suggest you remove `newPerson2` and change the Country Name dropdown and Country Code input as follows:

```
<InputSelect @bind-Value="@newPerson.CountryCode">
    <option value="0">Select</option>

    @foreach (var item in Countries)
    {
        <option value="@item.CountryCode">@item.CountryName</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

```
<div class="col-12 row">
    <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">Country Code:</label>
    <InputText id="CountryCode" @bind-Value="@newPerson.CountryCode" placeholder="CountryCode" />
    &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => newPerson.CountryCode)" />
</div>
```

Then down in `InsertSchool()` you should of course use `newPerson`: `CountryCode = newPerson.CountryCode`.

I haven't tested the above, but I expect it should work. What it means is that your dropdown (`InputSelect`) will set the value of `newPerson.CountryCode` based on your choice. When this happens, the Country Code `Input` will be updated by showing `newPerson.CountryCode` as well as ensuring the `CountryCode` is filled out when saving it to the DB.

Comment: This pulls the countryName but didn't pull the corresponding CountryCode automatically. I think this is because of the structure of the table. The country table has CountryName and CountryCode(PK) and the School table has the CountryCode as a foreign key from the country table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
 [SchoolID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Location] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [PostCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 [CountryCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
 [SchoolAdminPersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [SchoolID] ASC go
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[School]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_School_Country] FOREIGN KEY([CountryCode])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Country] ([CountryCode])
GO

Comment: @SQLBen Ah, I see I made an error in my second code snippet. I had entered `@bind-Value="@newPerson.CountryName"` but it should have been `@bind-Value="@newPerson.CountryCode"`. I updated my answer. Please try to use the updated code in the second snippet.

Comment: I just changed the structure of the table to include an INT ID column and the whole dropdown stopped working.

Comment: please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61384332/blazor-cascading-dropdown-menu-on-inputselect-not-loading