# Blazor - Cascading Dropdown menu on InputSelect not loading

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to load the below table, however, the drop-down menu for the school is not loading. It looks to me like it's null. And I figured that the InputSelect doesn't work with an INT ID yet in Blazor.

I filled the below for and the country code was populated from a country table as a lookup based on the country chosen from the InputSelect column, "Country Name", circled in blue. When I select the country, I expect it to load the correspionding countrycode but not the case.

```
      Razor Page

        @using ITSM.Data
        @using ITSM.Services

        @inject ISchoolService service
        @inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime



        <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="schoolmodal">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">School Detail</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">


        @if (CountryList is null)
        {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        }
        else
        {

        <h4>Schools</h4>
        <EditForm Model="@SchoolObject" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />
        <ValidationSummary />

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Location" CountryCode">Country Code:</label>
        <InputSelect @bind-Value="@SchoolObject.CountryCode" class="form-control">
        <option value="0">Select</option>

        @foreach (var item in CountryList)
        {
        <option value="@item.CountryCode">@item.CountryName</option>

        }
        </InputSelect>
        &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => @CountryObject.CountryCode)" />
        }
        </div>
        <br />



        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-2 font-weight-bold">Country Code:</label>
        <InputText id="CountryCode" @bind-Value="@SchoolObject.CountryCode" class="form-control"    placeholder="CountryCode" />
        &nbsp;<ValidationMessage For="@(() => SchoolObject.CountryCode)" />
        </div>



          Tables Structure

                CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
                    [CountryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                    [CountryCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
                    [CountryName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
                ) ON [PRIMARY]


            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[School](
            [SchoolID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Location] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
            [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
            [PostCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
            [CountryCode] [char](3) NOT NULL,
            [SchoolAdminPersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
         CONSTRAINT [PK_School] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [SchoolID] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]





        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>


        </EditForm>
        }

        </div>
        </div>

        </div>

        </div>





        @code {
        private List<CountryModel> CountryList;
        //private List<SchoolModel> SchoolList;
        [Parameter]
        public SchoolModel CountryObject { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public SchoolModel SchoolObject { get; set; }
        protected string schoold = string.Empty;

        [Parameter]
        public Action DataChanged { get; set; }



        private async Task Closeschoolmodal()
        {
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("CloseModal", "schoolmodal");
        }


        private async void HandleValidSubmit()
        {
        if (SchoolObject.SchoolID == 0)
        {
        await service.Add(SchoolObject);
        }
        else
        {
        await service.Update(SchoolObject);
        }
        await Closeschoolmodal();
        DataChanged?.Invoke();
        }


        }





      SchoolList

        @page "/SchoolList"

        @using ITSM.Shared
        @using ITSM
        @using ITSM.Data
        @using ITSM.Services
        @inject ISchoolService service
        @inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

        <h1>School</h1>

        <p>Countries List.</p>

        @if (SchoolLists == null)
        {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        }
        else
        {
        <br>
        <div>
        <input type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#schoolmodal" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add School" @onclick="(() => InitializeTaskObject())" />
        </div>
        <br/>

        <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>SchoolID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>PostCode</th>
        <th>CountryCode</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var SchoolItem in SchoolLists)
        {
        <tr>
        <td>@SchoolItem.SchoolID</td>
        <td>@SchoolItem.Name</td>
        <td>@SchoolItem.Location</td>
        <td>@SchoolItem.Address</td>
        <td>@SchoolItem.PostCode</td>
        <td>@SchoolItem.CountryCode</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => PrepareForEdit(SchoolItem))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#schoolmodal" value="Edit"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="(() => PrepareForDelete(SchoolItem))" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeleteModal" value="Delete" /></td>
        </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
        </table>
        }


        <ConfirmDialog OnClick="@Delete" />
        <SchoolDetail SchoolObject=SchoolObject DataChanged="@DataChanged"></SchoolDetail>




        @code {
        List<SchoolModel> SchoolLists;
        SchoolModel SchoolObject = new SchoolModel();

        private void PrepareForEdit(SchoolModel School)
        {
        SchoolObject = School;
        }

        private void PrepareForDelete(SchoolModel School)
        {
        SchoolObject = School;
        }

        private async void Delete()
        {
        var School = await service.Delete(SchoolObject.SchoolID);
        await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("Closemodal", "confirmDeletemodal");
        SchoolLists = await service.Get();
        SchoolObject = new SchoolModel();
        StateHasChanged();
        }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
        SchoolLists = await service.Get();

        }
        private void InitializeTaskObject()
        {
        SchoolObject = new SchoolModel();
        }
        private async void DataChanged()
        {
        SchoolLists = await service.Get();
        StateHasChanged();
        }
        }


     [![Snapshot of the dropdown menu][1]][1]
```

[image: Snapshot of the html page]

Comment: Check to see if your list has any entries. If there are no entries, nothing will be displayed. Just output the length.

Comment: Yes, there are entries on the list.

Comment: Can show me the created html from the select in Browser to see what exactly is created?

Comment: In my opinion, a few possibilities may be guilty of this. A) the list is empty or has no elements (check with a simple <p>CountryList.Count()</p> ) B) the list is not visible (check the generated html code) C) the change of the list is not processed correctly. You would have to use StateHasChanged() for this. Unfortunately your example code does not show the assignment of the list or the loading.

Comment: @Taladan, the html has been added.

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem yet. In your SchoolDetail your CountryList is null. You don't assign the CountryList by parameter or somewhere else in SchoolDetail from parent object.
You must load/create one in SchoolDetail or in inject from SchoolList by parameter a loaded/created list. 
In JavaScript are (sometimes) created variables in subcode visible. In Blazor/C# you must transport it from one to another.

Here a Example. Change in SchoolDetail

```
//private List<SchoolModel> SchoolList;
[Parameter] public List<CountryModel> CountryList { get; set; } = null;
```

And change in SchoolList.

```
<SchoolDetail SchoolObject="@SchoolObject" CountryList="@YourCountryList" DataChanged="@DataChanged"></SchoolDetail>
```

I don't see your CountryList there. You must Load or Create one there.

I recommend to write the objects this way, then you will find them later better in the code with one look.

```
SchoolObject="@SchoolObject"
```